# Closed form expression for the following sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have come across a sequence and am wondering if anyone knows of a closed form expression for it. I am a bit too lazy to figure it out on my own seeing as it is such a minor part of what I am doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The sequence is $c_{jk}$ such that $c_{(j+1)(k+1)} = c_{(j+1)k} - c_{jk}$ and $c_{j0} = 0$ for $j \neq 0$ and $c_{0k} = 1$ for $k\ge 0$

Comment: -1: That's motivating, you are too lazy to do it so you want someone here to do it.

Comment: I'm too lazy to post an answer seeing as its such a minor part of this site.

Comment: Yeah @JmsNxn : that lazy bit in your post isn't the most intelligent thing to say to someone you're asking for help. In fact, I can't think of many dumber things than that one to say when asking for help....hmmm.

Comment: The initial conditions that you’ve given are insufficient to determine the array. You need to specify $c_{j0}$ for $j>1$, and if you want values of $c_{jk}$ for $j<k$ you also need to specify $c_{0k}$ for $k>0$.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. That makes a lot of sense, I wrote it in a rush. I made the necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a small table of values gives the game away:

$$\begin{array}{c|rr}
j\backslash k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\ \hline
0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7\\
2&0&0&1&3&6&10&15&21\\
3&0&0&0&-1&-4&-10&-20&-35\\
4&0&0&0&0&1&5&15&35\\
5&0&0&0&0&0&-1&-6&-21\\
6&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&7\\
7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-1
\end{array}$$

Clearly $$c_{jk}=(-1)^j\binom{k}j\;.$$

And indeed

$$(-1)^{j+1}\binom{k}{j+1}-(-1)^j\binom{k}j=(-1)^{j+1}\left(\binom{k}{j+1}+\binom{k}j\right)=(-1)^{j+1}\binom{j+1}{k+1}\;,$$

verifying the conjecture.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had a feeling it had something to do with binomial coefficients. This is beautiful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JmsNxn: You’re very welcome!